# Pin website to Internet Explorer Jumplist

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, jumplist

I know from right clicking on Internet Explorer that somehow it's possible to pin particular URLs.  Also, I can take frequently accessed urls and pin those, but how can I add a new URL to the jumplist?

[image: IE Jumplist]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [IE 9 taskbar icon and Pinned items](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/17300460-df23-48f4-8c9b-0d2c376c0aef/):

> There is a way to achieve the old behavior:
>
> 1. Press and hold down the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key
> 2. Drag the favicon over the IE taskbar icon
> 3. Release the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key while still holding down the mouse
> 4. You will see the tooltip becomes to "Pin to Internet Explorer"
> 5. Then drop to pin
>
> Alternatively, you can drag & drop any `.url` file to the IE icon to pin it.
>
> 1. Drag & drop a favicon from IE9 to the desktop to get a `.website` file.
> 2. Then you can press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> to drag & drop to get the `.url` file.
> 3. Press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> after drag does not work